# Use of underscore and map fuction in dataframes/scala

Tags: scala, function, apache-spark, dataframe

I'm trying to understand the use of `map` function and that underscore `_` in the code below. `keys` is a `List[String]` and `df` is a `DateFrame`. I run an sample and found out listOfVal is a list of column type, but could someone help to explain how this works? What does `_` mean in this case and what gets applied by `map` fuction? Many thanks

`val listOfVal = keys.map(df(_))`

ps: I've read the two questions suggested but I think they are different use cases

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Underscores in a Scala map/foreach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47006863/underscores-in-a-scala-map-foreach)  and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37598649/why-can-i-not-flatmap-a-listoption-using-underscore

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Scala, `_` can act as a place-holder for an anonymous function.  For example:

```
List("A", "B", "C").map(_.toLowerCase)
// `_.toLowerCase` represents anonymous function `x => x.toLowerCase`
// res1: List[String] = List(a, b, c)

List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5).foreach(print(_))
// `print(_)` represents anonymous function `x => print(x)`
// res2: 12345
```

In your sample code, `keys.map(df(_))` is equivalent to:

```
keys.map(c => df(c))
```

Let's say your `keys` is a list of column names:

```
List[String]("col1", "col2", "col3")
```

Then it simply gets mapped to:

```
List[Column](df("col1"), df("col2"), df("col3"))
```

Comment: Thanks @Leo C I think it explains my question perfectly. Accepted the answer and upvoted.